# How to unit test if an angular 2 component contains another component

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I'm quite new to angular 2.

I have a component which in turn has some other components in its template.

How do I write unit tests to check if my parent component consists of other components.

Mentioning a sample or directing me to a resource would be really helpful.

MyComponent.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'my-component',
templateUrl: `<div>
<other-component></other-component>
</div>`
})
export class MyComponent{

}
```

OtherComponent.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'other-component',
templateUrl: `<div>
<h1>Other Component</h1>
</div>`
})
export class OtherComponent{

}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To test if a component, when compiled, contains other components:

- Inject the component you're testing
- Inject the child components
- Create the parent component
- Detect changes
- Use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` to find the child components

I typically only check that the element exists and then do further testing in the spec for the individual child component.

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OtherComponent } from './other/other.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        OtherComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should have the other component', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('app-other')).not.toBe(null);
  }));
});
```

Checking for null with `querySelector` will determine if your component exists. From the [querySelector MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> Returns null if no matches are found; otherwise, it returns the first
>   matching element.

---

If you'd like to check that there are multiple instances of the same child component, you can use `querySelectorAll` and check the `length` property:

```
expect(compiled.querySelectorAll('app-other').length).toBeGreaterThan(4);
```

Comment: Nice, wasn't sure how to accomplish this. Is checking it's not null the only thing we can do at this stage?

Answer (score 15):

In most cases you are just testing the outer component. If you just want angular to ignore the inner components, the easiest way is to add the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA to your spec.

import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'

And then in your TestBed.configureTestingModule add the line:

schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]

The tests will then ignore the fact that you have not imported the inner components in your component HTML.

If you want to test the inner component with your outer components, if you're using the angular-cli, you'll see that the component.spec file they automatically generate for you includes a `declarations` array that is part of the TestBed configuration object. So all you have to do is import the file and add the component into your declarations.

So your example above:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { MyComponent } from './my-component.component';
import { OtherComponent } from './other-component.component';
```

Then in your `describe` block you will have a `beforeEach`

```
beforeEach(async(() =>{
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ MyComponent,
                    OtherComponent ]
  })
  .compileComponent();
})
```

Then your components should now compile correctly without errors. If you want to see the whole setup, just generate a new project in angular-cli and take a look at the spec docs that it generates.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question they had. They want to ensure that a component exists in the template not test the inner component from the outer one or test the component independently.